# How to map pandas results after pivot_table aggregation?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table, map-function

I have some data of tests passed like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [[np.random.choice(['Tmax', 'Tmin']), np.random.choice(['USA', 'FRA', 'AUS']),
         np.random.randint(1,4), np.random.choice(['Class A', 'Class B']),np.random.randint(4)] for i in range(1000)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['temp', 'region', 'method', 'slice', 'pass'])
```

I have pivotted the dataframe using `np.mean` function as follows:

```
pv = pd.pivot_table(df, 
               index=['temp', 'method'], 
               values=['pass'],
               columns=['slice', 'region'],
              aggfunc=(np.mean))
```

The values of the `'pass'` variable is the average of passed tests in the form of decimals like 0.45, 1.5 3.2..., however I want to map these results with the following function

```
def results_mapper(v):
    num_tests = np.round(v)
    if num_tests < 2:
        return 1
    elif num_tests == 2:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3
```

I tried to map the results using `pv.map(results_mapper)`, or `map(results_mapper, pv)` but no luck.

**Sample numbers:**
the `pv` output numbers could be like `0.5, 1.1, 1.49, 1.6, 1.9, 2.1, 2.9, 3.5`

would be mapped to `1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3`

How can I apply the mapping function to my results by keeping the pivot table format as it is?

Comment: can you include a dummy desired output?

Comment: Yes, I will... Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.vectorize`

```
func = np.vectorize(results_mapper)
pv.values[:,:] = func(pv.values)
```

#### Output

```
              pass                            
slice       Class A           Class B          
region          AUS  FRA  USA     AUS  FRA  USA
temp method                                    
Tmax 1          1.0  1.0  2.0     2.0  2.0  1.0
     2          1.0  2.0  1.0     1.0  1.0  1.0
     3          1.0  2.0  2.0     2.0  2.0  2.0
Tmin 1          2.0  1.0  2.0     2.0  1.0  2.0
     2          2.0  2.0  1.0     2.0  1.0  2.0
     3          2.0  1.0  1.0     2.0  2.0  1.0
```

Comment: GREAT solution, Thank you very much.